# Issue with Mobile Menu on Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile-website

Hopefully this is the last time I will need to ask for your guys help: Website 3six-d.co.uk

Everything if fine on the normal website, issueshowever appear when I try to use it on mobiles.

http://mobiletest.me/iphone_5_emulator/#u=http://3six-d.co.uk/index.html

I'm giving that link to show you, but the same occurrence happens on my phone aswell.

This is the relevant code in the .js file (I could be wrong but I think it is)

```
$(function() {  
    var trigger = $('#responsive-nav');  
        menu = $('#main-nav ul');

    $(trigger).on('click', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();  
        menu.slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('nav-visible');
    }); 

    $(window).resize(function(){  
        var windowW = $(window).width();  
        if(windowW > mobileRes && menu.is(':hidden')) {  
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }  
    }); 
});
```

A weird ocurance was, that initially the jQuery was being called at the end of the html and it worked fine, but it was necessary to move it to the top for Fancybox and other scripts I am running. That is what is causing the problem, as soon as the following code is at the stop of the HTML document, the navigation menu stops working on mobiles and tablets:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any ideas guys, would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try using a timeout to see if it's a race condition?

Comment: Sorry I'm really unfamiliar with js which is why this is causing me such an issue, my only real knowledge stands with HTML and CSS, so I am super confused :(

Comment: I just looked at the site: jquery.fancybox.pack.ja should be "jquery.fancybox.pack.js" (you have jquery being called twice) ALSO: try to call jQuery at the top and everything else at the bottom, directly above the closing body tag. it's not the best way but it will allow you to control some of the dependencies.

Comment: I swear I tried that, but it worked anyway! Any chance you could take a look at a different think. On that website the only device the website doesnt work on seems on be an ipad, where the products page is way to the left compared to the other tabs, any ideas :) you are a star!

Comment: use .container-fluid instead of .row

Comment: Even on the regular website, on the About tab for example the text is all indented, while on the other pages is is not :/ Trying your method now

Comment: Well it sort of worked :) now everything is offset by different amounts significantly, http://mobt.me/5wde

Comment: That's because your using row in the child elements. Change them to col-md-12 or remove the element all together. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not using Bootstrap V3 so I assume you mean span?

Comment: eeek.  i don't remember the previous version. Sorry. If you want to try just using the container-fluid on the first child .row element inside of your parent .row... that may work too. Good luck. sorry I can't be of more help.